# Fresh install of 14.04 - now unable to connect to Unifi Access point (others work)

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

After installing 14.04 is can no longer connect to my Unifi Access Point (worked in 13.10 and works from windows on dual-boot machine). After a long pause, simply asks for password again.

Syslog generates the following ...

```
[ 1402.786355] wlan0: authenticate with c2:9f:db:87:99:d8
[ 1402.843630] wlan0: send auth to c2:9f:db:87:99:d8 (try 1/3)
[ 1402.845689] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1402.845899] wlan0: AP has invalid WMM params (AIFSN=1 for ACI 2), disabling WMM
[ 1402.847545] wlan0: associate with c2:9f:db:87:99:d8 (try 1/3)
[ 1402.850340] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c2:9f:db:87:99:d8 (capab=0x431 status=37 aid=0)
[ 1402.850347] wlan0: c2:9f:db:87:99:d8 denied association (code=37)
[ 1402.857675] wlan0: deauthenticating from c2:9f:db:87:99:d8 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1406.265427] wlan0: authenticate with c2:9f:db:87:99:d8
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`:

```
<snip>
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:4238] (rev 3e)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1111]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the Unifi? Rebooting the router fixes this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem occur on two machines connecting to Ubiquiti's UAP-LR access point. No matter what I tried I could not get this to work by tweaking the config / modules, etc. on the laptops.

I was running 2.4.6 of the unifi controller software, which is the latest "stable" version. I installed 3.2.1 which immediately upgraded the firmware on my AP and this resolved my problem. Both machines can now connect.

If your controller is running on Ubuntu, simply run:

`sudo apt-get install unifi-rapid`

This will automatically upgrade. Be sure to make a backup of your config first.

Answer (score -2):

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Comment: Care to expand a little?

Comment: Posting this file does not answer the question.